# What's the output of an Embedding layer in tensorflow and what does GlobalAveragePooling1D do it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm having trouble understanding what a 1D global average pooling does to an embedding layer. I know that embedding layers are like lookup tables. If I have `tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size=30, embedding_dim=7, input_length=10)`, is the output after feed forwarding a matrix of `10 rows x 7 columns` or a 3D tensor of `1 row x 7 columns x 10 length`?

If it's `10 rows x 7 columns`, does it take the average of each row and output a single vector of shape `10 row x 1 columns`?

If it's `1 row x 7 columns x 10 length`, does it take the average of each vector and output a single vector also in shape `10 row x 1 columns`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To your first question**:
*What's the output of an Embedding layer in tensorflow?*

The `Embedding` layer maps each integer value in a sequence that represents a unique word in the vocabulary to a 7-dimensional vector. In the following example, you have two sequences with 10 integer values each. These integer values can range from 0 to 29, where 30 is the size of the vocabulary. Each integer value of each sequence is mapped to a 7-dimensional vector, resulting in the output shape `(2, 10, 7)`, where 2 is the number of samples, 10 is the sequence length and 7 is the dimension of each integer value:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 2
texts = tf.random.uniform((samples, 10), maxval=30, dtype=tf.int32)

embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(30, 7, input_length=10)
print(embedding_layer(texts))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0.0225671   0.02347589  0.00979777  0.00041901 -0.00628462
    0.02810872 -0.00962182]
  [-0.00848696 -0.04342243 -0.02836052 -0.00517335 -0.0061365
   -0.03012114  0.01677728]
  [ 0.03311044  0.00556745 -0.00702027  0.03381392 -0.04623893
    0.04987461 -0.04816799]
  [-0.03521906  0.0379228   0.03005264 -0.0020758  -0.0384485
    0.04822161 -0.02092661]
  [-0.03521906  0.0379228   0.03005264 -0.0020758  -0.0384485
    0.04822161 -0.02092661]
  [-0.01790254 -0.0175228  -0.01194855 -0.02171307 -0.0059397
    0.02812174  0.01709754]
  [ 0.03117083  0.03501941  0.01058724  0.0452967  -0.03717183
   -0.04691924  0.04459465]
  [-0.0225444   0.01631368 -0.04825303  0.02976335  0.03874404
    0.01886607 -0.04535152]
  [-0.01405543 -0.01035894 -0.01828993  0.01214089 -0.0163126
    0.00249451 -0.03320551]
  [-0.00536104  0.04976835  0.03676006 -0.04985759 -0.04882429
    0.04079831 -0.04694915]]

 [[ 0.02474061  0.04651412  0.01263839  0.02834389  0.01770737
    0.027616    0.0391163 ]
  [-0.00848696 -0.04342243 -0.02836052 -0.00517335 -0.0061365
   -0.03012114  0.01677728]
  [-0.02423838  0.00046005  0.01264722 -0.00118362 -0.04956226
   -0.00222496  0.00678415]
  [ 0.02132202  0.02490019  0.015528    0.01769954  0.03830704
   -0.03469712 -0.00817447]
  [-0.03713315 -0.01064591  0.0106518  -0.00899752 -0.04772154
    0.03767705 -0.02580358]
  [ 0.02132202  0.02490019  0.015528    0.01769954  0.03830704
   -0.03469712 -0.00817447]
  [ 0.00416059 -0.03158562  0.00862025 -0.03387908  0.02394537
   -0.00088609  0.01963869]
  [-0.0454465   0.03087567 -0.01201812 -0.02580545  0.02585572
   -0.00974055 -0.02253721]
  [-0.00438716  0.03688161  0.04575384 -0.01561296 -0.0137012
   -0.00927494 -0.02183568]
  [ 0.0225671   0.02347589  0.00979777  0.00041901 -0.00628462
    0.02810872 -0.00962182]]], shape=(2, 10, 7), dtype=float32)
```

When working with text data, the output of an `Embedding` layer would be 2 sentences consisting of 10 words each, where each word is mapped to a 7-dimensional vector.

If you are wondering where these random numbers for each integer in each sequence come from, by default the `Embedding` layer uses a uniform distribution to generate these values.

**To your second question**:
*What does a 1D global average pooling do to an Embedding layer?*

The layer `GlobalAveragePooling1D` does nothing more than simply calculate the average over a given dimension in a tensor. The following example calculates the average of the 7 numbers representing a word in each sequence and returns a scalar for each word, resulting in the output shape `(2, 10)`, where 2 is the number of samples (sentences) and 10 represents the average values for of each word. This is equivalent to simply doing `tf.reduce_mean(embedding_layer(texts), axis=-1)`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

samples = 2
texts = tf.random.uniform((samples, 10), maxval=30, dtype=tf.int32)

embedding_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(30, 7, input_length=10)
average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format = "channels_first")
print(average_layer(embedding_layer(texts)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`GlobalAveragePooling1D` reduces the dimension of a matrix by taking the average along values of some dimension.

From the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/global_average_pooling1d/) this layer has a `data_format` argument. By default it is `"channels_last"` meaning that it will keep the last channel, and take the average along the other.

Here is an example model:

```py
model = Sequential([
    Input((10)),
    Embedding(30, 7, input_length=10),
    GlobalAveragePooling1D()
])

model.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_1 (Embedding)     (None, 10, 7)             210       
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling1d (G  (None, 7)                0         
 lobalAveragePooling1D)                                          
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 210
Trainable params: 210
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, the dimension for a sample was reduced from (10, 7) to (7), meaning **it returns the average of the embeddings given**.

If you set `data_format = "channels_first"`, like here

```py
model = Sequential([
    Input((10)),
    Embedding(30, 7, input_length=10),
    GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format = "channels_first")
])

model.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding_1 (Embedding)     (None, 10, 7)             210       
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling1d (G  (None, 10)                0         
 lobalAveragePooling1D)                                          
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 210
Trainable params: 210
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Here the dimension for a sample was reduced from (10, 7) to (10), meaning **it returns the average of values in each embeddings given**. What kind of doesn't make sense, since you could set the `embedding_dim` to 1 and get the same result.

Comment: Can you clarify what the ouput of the embedding layer looks like? Is it a matrix where each row corresponds to a word?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is a matrix where every row is a word. Interesting thing that after GlobalAveragePooling1D l, which is averaging every column of that matrix, there is no any sense that we (humans) could understand. Please, smarter people, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: So, ran some examples with 'channels_first' and 'channels_last'. Intiuitively, we should get an output of 'None,10'. That means for each word we get a single value and 'channel_first' works like this. However when I do so, accuracy crumbles(38%). Using 'channels_last' we get 'None,7', which means average pooling each n-th feature of words. This gives better accuracy (85%) but still couldn't figure out how so. In my opinion getting the embedding from the same order of each word and averaging them shouldn't work out.

Comment: Clarification to previous comment. It's like there are 10 people with each 7 traits and you need to assess their personalities. You should simply take traits for each person and return a personality value that means 'None,10'. Getting first, second, third and so forth traits for every people and averaging shouldn't help at all. That means something like individual trait averaging. But apparently this works. Or I'm making some mistakes while interpreting this or thinking like a total noob.